What happens to a coherent state when it passes through an optical amplifier?
I learned from this article that when a quantum state passes through an optical amplifier based on stimulated emission (e.g., EDFA), the variance of its quadrature becomes:
$(\Delta X)^2 = G(\Delta X_0)^2 + (2 n_\text{sp} - 1)(G - 1) \frac{1}{4}$
where $X_0$ is the quadrature of the input state, $X$ is the quadrature of the output state, $G$ is the gain, and $n_\text{sp} = \frac{N_2}{N_2 - N_1}$ is a factor depending on the popular inversion.
The first term $G(\Delta X_0)^2$ is because the noise of the input is amplified by $G$ times. The second term is due to the amplified spontaneous emission (ASE), where the variance of a vacuum state is $\frac{1}{4}$ and is amplified by $(2 n_\text{sp} - 1)(G - 1)$ times. This is illustrated in the following figure:

This result is achieved by perturbatively calculating the variance of the quadrature operator in the Heisenberg picture, the dynamics being given by the Tavis-Cummings model.
Now my questions are:
(1) Is there a closed from of the quantum channel for this optical amplifier?
(2) Given that the input state is a coherent state, what does the output state look like, in the Fock state basis or in the coherent state basis (Wigner function)?

Edit: Note that this optical amplifier is not based on the $\chi^{(2)}$ or $\chi^{(3)}$ nonlinear parametric process, so it does not give rise to squeezing. The quadratures with all phases are amplified in the same fashion.
The optical amplifier based on squeezing is treated in the article mentioned above, but is not relevant to this question. Though both of my questions can also be asked about this squeezing amplifier.

It seems you're interested in what is called "Squeezed States", characterized by the squeezing of one of the quadrature (and anti-squeezing of the other). Maybe the article "Squeezed light" by A. I. Lvovsky will answer your question :)

@ChrisZeThird Squeezed states don't arise here. This is an optical amplifier based on popular inversion rather than $\chi^{(2)}$ nonlinear parametric process. So here if you calculate the variance for quadratures with any phase, you will find that all of them are amplified in the same fashion, hence no squeezing. In the article I mentioned in my question, there is some treatment to the optical amplifier based on $\chi^{(2)}$ nonlinearity, which will give rise to squeezed states.
